# Python: How to set a timeout on receiving data in SocketServer.TCPServer

Tags: python, sockets, timeout, socketserver

I've read quite a few things and this still escapes me. I know how to do it when using raw sockets. The following works just fine, times out after 1 second if no data is received:

```py
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
sock.listen(1)
while 1:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    data = ''
    conn.settimeout(1)
    try:
        while 1:
            chunk = conn.recv(1024)
            data += chunk
            if not chunk:
                break
        print 'Read: %s' % data
        conn.send(data.upper())
    except (socket.timeout, socket.error, Exception) as e:
        print(str(e))
    finally:
        conn.close()
        print 'Done'
```

But when trying something similar when using `SocketServer.TCPServer` with `SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler` (not with `SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler` where I know how to set a timeout) it seems not as trivial. I didn't find a way to set a timeout for receiving the data. Consider this snippet (not complete code):

```py
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = ''
        while 1:
            chunk = self.request.recv(1024)
            data += chunk
            if not chunk:
                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 9987
    SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Suppose the client sends only 10 bytes. The while loop runs once, chunk is not empty, so then executes `self.request.recv()` again but the client has no more data to send and recv() blocks indefinitely ...

I know I can implement a small protocol, check for terminating strings/chars, check message length etc., but I really want to implement a timeout as well for unforeseen circumstances (client "disappears" for example).

I'd like to set *and also update* a timeout, i.e. reset the timeout after every `chunk`, needed for slow clients (though that's a secondary issue at the moment).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked into this? http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html?highlight=tcpserver#SocketServer.BaseServer.timeout

Comment: That's for handling (waiting for) requests. When serve_forever() is called, the .timeout property is ignored (see the same page you linked to). My question regards timeouts for receiving data, i.e. after a client has connected.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the same thing with `SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler.request.settimeout()` as you did with the raw socket.

eg:

```
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.request.settimeout(1)
        ...
```

In this case `self.request.recv()` will terminate if it takes longer than 1 second to complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
timeout=5
...
```

... will raise an exception (which serve_forever() will catch) and shut down the connection if 5 seconds pass without receiving data after calling recv(). Be careful, though; it'll also shut down your connection if you're *sending* data for more than 5 seconds as well.

This may be Python 3 specific, mind, but it works for me.